# How Can I check how many up votes I have made?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can I find out how many times i have vote up for any question or answer?

Means do i get the total count of up votes or down votes i have made.

Answer (score 3):

In the bottom right of your profile is a "Votes Cast" section. It'll tell you everything you want to know there, including a link to *view more*, which takes you to your profile's *Votes* tab, giving an in-depth beak down of all the posts you've voted on.

Mine currently looks like this:

[image: Votes Cast]